# Rails: correct way of turning activerecord relation to array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I was trying to select objects uniq by one attribute, using `@videos.uniq{|p| p.author}`

```
  time = Time.new(2014, 12)
  start_time = time.beginning_of_month
  end_time = time.end_of_month

  videos = Video.where("created_at > ? AND created_at < ?", start_time, end_time).where("likes > ?", 15)
  selected_videos = videos.uniq{|p| p.author}
  puts videos.count, videos.class, selected_videos.count 
 #=> 23, Video::ActiveRecord_Relation, 23

  videos_first = videos.first(23)
  selected_videos = videos_first.uniq{|p| p.author}
  puts videos_first.count, videos_first.class, selected_videos.count
  #=> 23, array, 10
```

`.uniq` is not for `ActiveRecord_Relation`. And the problem is that the query returns a `Video::ActiveRecord_Relation`, but I need `array`.

Certainly, this could be achieved by using `to_a`, but is this elegant?

1. What's the correct way of handling this ?
2. Is it possible to use `.uniq` for `activerecord:relation`?

Comment: `to_a` is the correct way of turning *anything* into an array.

Comment: careful about the n+1 query. You'll have a more efficient query using `Video.where(...).includes(:author)` before calling `.to_a.uniq{|p| p.author}`

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you need to access to the query result, just use `#to_a` on ActiveRecord::Relation instance.

At [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.8/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-notable-changes) you can find on notable changes at Rails 4.0: "Model.all now returns an ActiveRecord::Relation, rather than an array of records. Use Relation#to_a if you really want an array. In some specific cases, this may cause breakage when upgrading." That is valid for other relation methods like :where.

```rb
selected_videos = videos.to_a.uniq{|p| p.author}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't know about the to_a method for active records... :)
Now I'm wondering if there's a list for active record methods... hmmmmm

Comment: @AlonSamuel visit https://api.rubyonrails.org and navigate to ActiveRecord >> Relation to see all its public methods.

Comment: @AlonSamuel You can also get list of methods via console (ActiveRecord.methods - Object.methods) or (ActiveRecord::Base.methods - Object.methods)

Answer (score 4):

`.uniq` does not make much sense when it is applied across the full active-record record.

Given that at least one or more of the three attributes - `id`, `created_at`, and `updated_at` - are different for every row, applying `videos.uniq{|p| p.author}` where `videos` is a `ActiveRecord::Relation` including all fields, will return all the rows in the `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

When the `ActiveRecord::Relation` object has a subset of values, `uniq` will be able to figure out the distinct values from them.

Eg: `videos.select(:author).uniq.count` will give 10 in your example.

The difference between `ActiveRecord::Relation#uniq` and `Array#uniq` is that the Array version accepts a block and uses the return value of a block for comparison. The ActiveRecord::Relation version of uniq simply ignores the block.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the records, you can use ActiveRecord::Relation#load

> Causes the records to be loaded from the database if they have not been loaded already. You can use this if for some reason you need to explicitly load some records before actually using them. The return value is the relation itself, not the records.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-load